# How do I do this with C? Fibonnacci Sequence

Tags: c

Perhaps someone could help me out with this.

- Using the concept of cycle generate the Fibonacci series until reaching 10000 or a little more than that.

So I have this code and it's supossed to work and show me what I want but it doesn't.
Can somebody tell me what's wrong with it? It opens but it doesn't work @_@

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
    int i=0,j=0,sum=1,num;

    while(sum>=1000){
    {
       printf("%d\n",sum);
        i=j;
        j=sum;
        sum=i+j;    

     } 
  system("pause");  
}
```

---

The code I made for calculating the Fibonacci sequence is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i=0,j=0,sum=1,num;
    printf("Introduce the limit for the Fibonacci sequence: ");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    while(sum<num)
    {
       printf("%d\n",sum);
        i=j;
        j=sum;
        sum=i+j;               
    }   
  system("pause");  
}
```

Comment: while sum >= 1000 means it will never start because sum = 1. I think you want <=

Comment: "Here's my code, it doesn't work..." _WHAT_ is it about it that doesn't work?!

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work. Maybe it's my compilator.

Comment: Rule for future: suspect the compiler last, your own code first.

Comment: Thanks. I am lost as it says until reaching 10000 or a little bit more than that.

Comment: Also, the reason you have 4 downvotes is because you said "It doesn't work'. People expect you to clearly define what is not working and how it is not working.

Comment: Okay (: Sorry for that. The code works when I say less or equal to 10000 however it doesn't work when I put bigger or equal to. I need the 10946 value to be shown as well.

Comment: second program change `while(sum<num)` to `while(j<num)`

Answer (score 1):

In the first snippet, you have a typo

```
while(sum>=1000){
```

should be

```
while (sum < 10000){
```

I said 'less than' rather than 'less than or equal to' because of the wording of your assignment.

You want to print out F<sub>n</sub> where F<sub>n</sub> is the first such number > 10000. Since `j` is really F<sub>n-1</sub> change the while loop condition to

```
while (j <= 10000)
{
```

Comment: I tried that but it should show me a little bit more than 10000.

Comment: Then it seems you haven't posted the code you are compiling.

Comment: The first one up there is the one I'm compiling. It doesn't show me anything. Just press to continue.

Comment: And that's because of the incorrect while loop condition. I give up.

Comment: Haha, I understand now. I have to change my while loop condition.

Comment: That's what I said 10 minutes ago.

Comment: Yeah I got it now. Sorry :p But it clearly says that it should show the value arround 10000. *Retypes the while loop cond*

Comment: @MitchWheat: This question was originally tagged with only the `regex` tag, so I wouldn't expect too much :).

Comment: @JesseGood: I'm a newbie here and I couldn't pick the right tag :)

Answer (score 0):

while sum >= 1000 means it will never start because sum = 1. I think you want <=. The second is an infinite loop because sum is always greater than num